# Graph API - failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, sdk, facebook-opengraph, token

I need your help to resolve a problem.
Sometime after I got the token this error happen when a try to get data about user:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

The code that execute this is:

```
 $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$token;
 $dados = @json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

How can I resolve this problem? Why this happen?

I searched a lot, but didn't find the  solution. Someone help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Paste your access token into the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). Is it valid and a *user* access token?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the PHP SDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

There´s also some example code if you scroll down to "Usage", including correct login handling. With that, you don´t really need to think about the Access Token, it all happens in the background. Also keep in mind that access tokens are valid for up to 2 hours only, if you want to extend it: Use the "setExtendedAccessToken" function of the PHP SDK to extend it to up to 60 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try urlencode() your token and pass the value to file_get_contents(). This may work.

```
file_get_contents will only work if you have allow_url_fopen = 1 in your php.ini
```

For remote file access like above, consider using the [cURL](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/allow_url_fopen.html) functions that PHP provides.

```
function url_get_contents ($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //get the code of request
    curl_close($ch);

    if($httpCode == 400) 
       return 'No donuts for you.';

    if($httpCode == 200) //is ok?
       return $output;


}
```